# How to sign a CSR on windows

Tags: windows, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

I've got a custom certificate that I'm using as a local root authority. This certifcate has a private key on my machine and is stored in the "Personal" certificates store of the "Local Machine" location.

I want to use this to sign a Certificate Signing Request file created by an outside organisation.

I've been searching documenation for ages and I can't find a way to do this using Microsoft tools. Does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Do you have the Certificate Authority (something like that) role installed? What Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. I wanted to avoid the need to set-up a full CA as all I really want is to sign a single cert.

Comment: You always need a “full CA”, otherwise you wouldn’t be able to sign, no? ;) If you want something less bulky, take a look at OpenSSL and [EasyRSA](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa).

Comment: @DanielB -- in theory I should only need a trusted root certificate with a private key. I don't want to install loads of services just to sign a single csr.

Comment: Yeah, well, that’s just how it is on Windows. Nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for codesign windows? It may be helpful [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'm not looking to sign code so I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for